# Confidence Interval and Standard error of Skewness and Kurtosis

Tags: r, standard-error, kurtosis

Please tell me how to calculate skewness and kurtosis along with their respective standard error and confidence interval associated with it(i.e. SE of Skewness and S.E of Kurtosis) I found two packages

1) package:**'measure'** can only calculate skewness and kurtosis

2) package:**'rela'**  can calcuate both skewness and kurtosis but uses bootstrap by default and no command to turn it off during the calculation.

Answer (score 5):

I'm simply copying and pasting the code published by Howard Seltman in [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/files/spssSkewKurtosis.R):

```
# Skewness and kurtosis and their standard errors as implement by SPSS
#
# Reference: pp 451-452 of
# http://support.spss.com/ProductsExt/SPSS/Documentation/Manuals/16.0/SPSS 16.0 Algorithms.pdf
# 
# See also: Suggestion for Using Powerful and Informative Tests of Normality,
# Ralph B. D'Agostino, Albert Belanger, Ralph B. D'Agostino, Jr.,
# The American Statistician, Vol. 44, No. 4 (Nov., 1990), pp. 316-321

spssSkewKurtosis=function(x) {
  w=length(x)
  m1=mean(x)
  m2=sum((x-m1)^2)
  m3=sum((x-m1)^3)
  m4=sum((x-m1)^4)
  s1=sd(x)
  skew=w*m3/(w-1)/(w-2)/s1^3
  sdskew=sqrt( 6*w*(w-1) / ((w-2)*(w+1)*(w+3)) )
  kurtosis=(w*(w+1)*m4 - 3*m2^2*(w-1)) / ((w-1)*(w-2)*(w-3)*s1^4)
  sdkurtosis=sqrt( 4*(w^2-1) * sdskew^2 / ((w-3)*(w+5)) )
  mat=matrix(c(skew,kurtosis, sdskew,sdkurtosis), 2,
        dimnames=list(c("skew","kurtosis"), c("estimate","se")))
  return(mat)
}
```

To get skewness and kurtosis of a variable along with their standard errors, simply run this function:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
spssSkewKurtosis(x)

##             estimate    se
##    skew       -0.684 0.241
##    kurtosis    0.273 0.478
```

Comment: Note that the SE formula used assumed x to be normally distributed.

Answer (score 4):

The standard errors are valid for normal distributions, but not for other distributions.  To see why, you can run the following code (which uses the `spssSkewKurtosis` function shown above) to estimate the true confidence level of the interval obtained by taking the kurtosis estimate plus or minus 1.96 standard errors:

```
set.seed(12345)
Nsim = 10000
Correct = numeric(Nsim)
b1.ols = numeric(Nsim)
b1.alt = numeric(Nsim)
for (i in 1:Nsim) {
 Data = rnorm(1000)  
 Kurt = spssSkewKurtosis(Data)[2,1]
 seKurt =  spssSkewKurtosis(Data)[2,2]
  LowerLimit = Kurt -1.96*seKurt
  UpperLimit = Kurt +1.96*seKurt
  Correct[i] = LowerLimit <= 0 & 0 <= UpperLimit  
 }

TrueConfLevel = mean(Correct)
TrueConfLevel
```

This gives you 0.9496, acceptably close to the expected 95%, so the standard errors work as expected when the data come from a normal distribution. But if you change `Data = rnorm(1000)` to `Data = runif(1000)`, then you are assuming that the data come from a uniform distribution, whose theoretical (excess) kurtosis is -1.2. Making the corresponding change from `Correct[i] = LowerLimit <= 0 & 0 <= UpperLimit` to `Correct[i] = LowerLimit <= -1.2 & -1.2 <= UpperLimit` gives the result 1.0, meaning that the 95% intervals were always correct, rather than correct for 95% of the samples.  Hence, the standard error seems to be overestimated (too large) for the (light-tailed) uniform distribution.

If you change `Data = rnorm(1000)` to `Data = rexp(1000)`, then you are assuming that the data come from an exponential distribution, whose theoretical (excess) kurtosis is 6.0. Making the corresponding change from `Correct[i] = LowerLimit <= 0 & 0 <= UpperLimit` to `Correct[i] = LowerLimit <= 6.0 & 6.0 <= UpperLimit` gives the result 0.1007, meaning that the 95% intervals were correct only for 10.07% of the samples, rather than correct for 95% of the samples.  Hence, the standard error seems to be underestimated (too small) for the (heavy-tailed) exponential distribution.

Those standard errors are grossly incorrect for non-normal distributions, as the simulation above shows. Thus, the only use of those standard errors is to compare the estimated kurtosis with the expected theoretical normal value (0.0); e.g., using a test of hypothesis. They cannot be used to construct a confidence interval for the true kurtosis.

Answer (score 1):

@HBat [is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54369572): provided your sample data is Gaussian, you can compute the standard error using the equation from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Sample_skewness)

```
n = len(sample)
se_skew = ((6*n*(n-1))/((n-2)*(n+1)*(n+3)))**0.5
```

However, @BigBendRegion [is also right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580348): if your data is not Gaussian, this does not work. Then you may need to bootstrap.

R has the [DescTools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DescTools/index.html) package that can bootstrap confidence intervals for skew (among other things). It can be included in python using `rpy2` like so:

```
""" Import rpy2 and the relevant package"""
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
DescTools = importr('DescTools')
""" You will probably need this if you want to work with numpy arrays"""
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()


def compute_skew(data, confidence_level=0.99):
    """ Compute the skew and confidence interval using rpy2, DescTools
        @param data
        @return dict with keys: skew, skew_ci_lower, skew_ci_upper"""
    d = {}
    d["skew"], d["skew_ci_lower"], d["skew_ci_upper"] = DescTools.Skew(data, conf_level=confidence_level)
    return d

""" Call the function on your data (assuming that is saved in a variable named sample)"""
print(compute_skew(sample))
```

Answer (score 0):

try package psych:

```
> a <- data.frame(cola=rep(c('A','B','C'),100),colb=sample(1:1000,300),colc=rnorm(300))
> describe(a)
      vars   n   mean     sd median trimmed    mad   min    max  range  skew kurtosis    se
cola*    1 300   2.00   0.82   2.00    2.00   1.48  1.00   3.00   2.00  0.00    -1.51  0.05
colb     2 300 511.76 285.59 506.50  514.21 362.50  1.00 999.00 998.00 -0.04    -1.17 16.49
colc     3 300   0.12   1.04   0.05    0.10   1.07 -2.54   2.91   5.45  0.12    -0.24  0.06
> describe(a)$skew
[1]  0.00000000 -0.04418551  0.11857609
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the standard error *of the skew and kurtosis themselves*

Comment: @Zahiro Mor I am interested in the SE of the skewness and kurtosis

Comment: SES and SEK can be calculated directly from the sample size n: where  SES = square root of a fraction, 6 n times n minus 1 on top, and n minus 2, times n+1, times n+3 on bottom

Comment: @ZahiroMor According to the link below they are the rough measure . http://www.real-statistics.com/tests-normality-and-symmetry/analysis-skewness-kurtosis/

Comment: check this out: https://estatistics.eu/what-is-statistics-standard-error-of-skewness-standard-error-of-kurtosis/

Comment: what you found is a rough estimate (sqrt(6/n) - I suggest using : `ses  <- function(n) {sqrt((6*n*(n-1))/((n-2)*(n+1)*(n+3)))}`

Comment: @ZahiroMor, does this work for non-normal samples as well? This formula can be used when the data comes from a normal distribution but when the distribution is, say, skewed, then I am not sure whether you can use the formula to calculate the standard error for of the estimate of skewness.

Answer (score 0):

```
def skew_kurt(dataframe: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:

out = []
for col in dataframe:
    
    x = dataframe[col]
    sd = x.std()
    
    if sd == 0:
        out.append({name: np.nan for name in ['skew stat', 'skew se', 'kurt stat', 'kurt se']})
        continue
    
    w, m1 = len(x), x.mean()
    dif = x - m1
    m2, m3, m4 = tuple([(dif ** i).sum() for i in range(2, 5)])
    
    skew = w * m3 / (w - 1) / (w - 2) / sd ** 3
    skew_se = np.sqrt(6 * w * (w - 1) / ((w - 2) * (w + 1) * (w + 3)))
    
    kurt = (w * (w + 1) * m4 - 3 * m2 ** 2 * (w - 1)) / ((w - 1) * (w - 2) * (w - 3) * sd ** 4)
    kurt_se = np.sqrt(4 * (w ** 2 - 1) * skew_se ** 2 / ((w - 3) * (w + 5)))

    out.append({'skew stat': skew, 'skew se': skew_se, 'kurt stat': kurt, 'kurt se': kurt_se})
    
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(out, index = list(dataframe))
dataframe['skew<2'] = np.absolute(dataframe['skew stat']) < 2 * dataframe['skew se']
dataframe['kurt<2'] = np.absolute(dataframe['kurt stat']) < 2 * dataframe['kurt se']
    
return dataframe[['skew stat', 'skew se', 'skew<2', 'kurt stat', 'kurt se', 'kurt<2']]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).